# Find tables with modified data after a specified datetime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am performing few inserts and updates on my database using tool provided by app supplier. I want to compare the updated database and backup after running the tool.

But my database size is around 250GB, that takes long time to compare. Rather than full database compare I want to compare the tables which are modified after running the tool.

How can I get all the table names those are modified after specified date like 2015-04-14?

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: @sabinbio Not returning any tables names in which data is inserted/updated.

Comment: You can track that with high accuracy **only** if your database has something like `LAST_CHANGED_DATE` or `LAST_UPDATED_DATE`.

Comment: @Kin How to find whether my database has `LAST_CHANGED_DATE `/`LAST_UPDATED_DATE`?

Comment: Look at the table schema and see if you have such column for tracking or not.

Comment: I have gone through few tables schema but none of them have `LAST_CHANGED_DATE /LAST_UPDATED_DATE` columns.

Comment: Then your best bet would be to use a server side trace or CDC.

Comment: Got the solution. 
`USE [Echo2]
GO

SELECT    [TableName] = OBJECT_NAME(object_id),
last_user_update, last_user_seek, last_user_scan, last_user_lookup
FROM    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
WHERE    database_id = DB_ID('Echo2') AND last_user_update >= '2015-04-14 15:07:25.987'
GO`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like

```
    SELECT
        [name]
       ,create_date
       ,modify_date
FROM
        sys.tables
```

you can add a WHERE clause to limit the results to only those changes that have occurred in the past week, month, year, whatever. Something like

```
SELECT
        [name]
       ,create_date
       ,modify_date
FROM
        sys.views
WHERE
        modify_date > DATEADD(day,-30,GETDATE())
```

Although this is no substitute for true database auditing that captures who modified the table, what was changed, and what the table looked like prior to the change.

To get the former, you'll need to invest some time in DDL triggers or some money into a third party tool.

Comment: Just FYI this tells you when a table was modified (e.g. `ALTER TABLE`), not updates/inserts.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ohh. I got few tables as a result, I thought those are the updated tables. Not sure whether they are altered tables or updated data tables.

Comment: I think it is true. I have created few records on the database manually through my app. But nothing showed up as updated tables this time.

Comment: @VaraPrasadPakalapati, that will capture the alter table scenarios. However as mentioned in answer, you can also create a trigger to track the changes: you can refer to link http://thesqldude.com/2012/06/01/auditing-t-sql-script-to-find-out-who-made-changes-to-data-in-a-table/

Answer (score -1):

you can also run to this query to get accurate details of when was  the table last updated. If WHERE condition is entirely removed it will provide details of the entire database.

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID) AS DatabaseName, last_user_update,*
 FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats
 WHERE database_id = DB_ID( 'YourDatabaseName')
 AND OBJECT_ID=OBJECT_ID('TableName')
```

Comment: This DMV is cleared each server restart, so your answer is a little misleading.

Comment: @MarkSinkinson,  I have talked Database-Scope DMV not the Server-scope DMV. So, I hope you would be agree with my statement.

Comment: No...If the Server is restarted, this DMV is cleared, regardless of whether it's database or server scoped...

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx **The counters are initialized to empty whenever the SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER) service is started. In addition, whenever a database is detached or is shut down (for example, because AUTO_CLOSE is set to ON), all rows associated with the database are removed**

Comment: @marksinkinson, Have you check out this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: No...I only linked to that article myself and posted a comment from it above. I certainly didn't read it... /sarcasm

Comment: @MarkSinkinson, i agree with you but My production environment there is MS SQL Server 2012.

Comment: I don't see what point you're trying to make? Both articles say the exact same thing that I posted in bold above. That the database counters are reset on server restart